# ElasticSerch match query result is empty

Tags: elasticsearch, search, solr

I have an index with documents that have 3 fields `name`, `summary` and `tags`

`name` is short text that contains small pharse e.g. "Japanese Handmade Sword"

`summary` is a long text that is description of certain products, it may be more then 200 words.

`tags` is an array of string with keywords, e.g. `["Japanese", "Antiquity", "Weapon", "Katana"]`

I need to combine these fields into one search query to get desired search results. For example, when user searched "Japan" I should get this item. However, `match` query always gives me empty result, although I have data and can see all documents without query.

Here is my mapping and index settings that performs some tokenization for fields.

```
PUT lessons
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_shards": 1
    },
    "refresh_interval": "5s",
    "similarity": {
      "string_similarity": {
        "type": "BM25"
      }
    },
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "autocomplete": {
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "standard"
        },
        "autocomplete_search": {
          "type": "custom",
          "filter": "lowercase",
          "tokenizer": "standard"
        }
      },
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
        "search_analyzer": "autocomplete_search",
        "fielddata": true,
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "summary": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
        "search_analyzer": "autocomplete_search",
        "fielddata": true,
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "tags": {
        "type": "text",
        "search_analyzer": "autocomplete_search",
        "fielddata": true,
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am using Kibana and when run below query I get no result

```
GET lessons/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "summary": "Japan"
    }
  }
}
```

What is wrong with my index settings or mapping?

Comment: Does your summary contains "Japan" string? Currently your match query is searching only on "summary", but as you said you need to combine these fields into one search query to get desired search results, does that mean you want to perform search in all these field and get result if any of those contain a matching text?

Comment: Right, it contains. but even for `multi_match` query I don't get a result

Comment: I inserted this doc                                                                                                  `POST lessons/_doc/1
{
  "name":"Japanese Handmade Sword",
  "summary":"Japanese Japan summary is a long text that is description of certain products, it may be more then 200 words",
  "tags":["Japanese", "Antiquity", "Weapon", "Katana"]
}`, when I perform multi_match, as given by @EScoder, it does return me the doc

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [multi-match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html), to search on multiple fields for the same query text

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query":    "Japan", 
      "fields": [ "summary", "tags", "name" ] 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Aren Hovsepyan did you get a chance to go through the answer, looking forward to get feedback from you ;-)